# How to find specific package name from list of installed packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to remove an old version of eclipse (3.8), but I don't know the package name. Can someone explain how to correctly find the package name?

I tried this, but when I did autoremove on those names it couldnt find the package:

```
king@king-Inspiron-7352 ~ $ apt list --installed |grep eclipse

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

eclipse-jdt/xenial,xenial,now 3.8.1-8 all [installed,automatic]
eclipse-pde/xenial,now 3.8.1-8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
eclipse-platform/xenial,now 3.8.1-8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
eclipse-platform-data/xenial,xenial,now 3.8.1-8 all [installed,automatic]
eclipse-rcp/xenial,now 3.8.1-8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libeclipse-aether-java/xenial,xenial,now 1.0.2-1 all [installed,automatic]
libeclipselink-java/xenial,xenial,now 2.5.1-3 all [installed,automatic]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try according to these commands:

Identify the program,

```
which eclipse
```

Look for the package using the output of the `which` command line for the path

```
dpkg -S /path/eclipse
```

I think the package name is `eclipse`. You can run

```
apt-cache policy eclipse
```

to see the versions. It seems to me that the version, that you have, 3.8.1-8, is the current one in 16.04.x LTS.

(I have not installed `eclipse`, but `apt-cache` shows the 'candidate' to be installed.)